# Stop HighCharts increasing width of line on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am using the latest version of HighCharts to build a chart with multiple trends. By default HighCharts increases the thickness / lineWidth of a line when the user's mouse hovers over it. Because I could have ~10 trends on the chart I would like to remove this feature, meaning that the thickness of the line does not change on hover.

[jsFiddle of code so far](http://jsfiddle.net/4oypoeom/4/)

I believe I need to set this in the plotOptions{} section. I have tried adding the following without success:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        mouseOver: {
            lineWidth: 2
        }
    },
    marker: {
        enabled: false,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 2
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I would, however, like to retain the marker that denotes where the mouse of positioned:

[image]

Comment: You can set a lineWidth as 1, http://jsfiddle.net/4oypoeom/5/.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make this below change (Set the `states` mouseover to disabled state)

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                 states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4oypoeom/2/)**

---

In that case make lineWidth: 1 for hover

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                 states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                }
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4oypoeom/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is very close to what I am looking for, but the one thing is that I want to keep the circle that appears on the trend on hover. I have updated the jsFiddle and the question. My apologies for not including this originally. http://jsfiddle.net/4oypoeom/4/

Comment: see my answer below. need for this type of set up has been replaced with newer property lineWidthPlus. makes it much easier to streamline your settings.

Answer (score 8):

What you need here is the `lineWidthPlus` property.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    states: {
      hover: {
        lineWidthPlus: 0
     }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, no matter what else you change, the chart will not change the lineWidth when hovered.

API Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.lineWidthPlus

Your fiddle updated:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4oypoeom/8/