# Remove line dots from the area spline chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I need  to remove the dots from the line of the line. I have seen this answer [Stop HighCharts increasing width of line on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252960/stop-highcharts-increasing-width-of-line-on-hover) But Did not work for me.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3o5kfd2/)

Here is my code

```
Highcharts.chart('graph_box', {
  chart: {
    type: 'areaspline',
    width: 300,
    height: 275
  },
  xAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    valueSuffix: ' units'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    areaspline: {
      fillOpacity: 0.5
    },
    series: {
      lineWidth: 2,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      lineColor: '#8b8bff',
      color: '#c5c6ff',
      lineWidth: '4px',
      data: [3, 8, 9, 5, 4, 10, 12, 6, 7, 1, 4, 6]
    }
  ]
})
```

Can someone please help!!

Comment: Hi @Profer, Could you explain more precisely what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ppotaczek Please have a look at the fiddle. You can see the dots on the line of chart. I need to remove that dots.

Comment: Do you mean the markers on hover? You can disable them in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wfzjtLux/

Comment: @ppotaczek Yes Followed the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series markers can be disabled in this way:

```
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4o023vxg/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.states.hover.enabled

Comment: There are more questions I need to ask related to the chart. Can I ask here Or ask a new question? Well I will up vote your answers for my every question in the comments

Comment: Hi @Profer, Please create new questions with `highcharts` tag and I will try to help you.

Comment: hi ppotaczek. Can I give the `width` and the `height` in percentage?

Comment: @Profer, You can set `height` in percentage: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height, but the best way is to use CSS styles: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/912uk4d8/